# Is there a way to return 0 if values does not exist in table using SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sum, left-join

I have put down below a query to retrieve from four tables which are

```
Sales_Invoice, New_Customer, Company_Information, Expense
```

Query:

```
select
    isnull(sum(Expense.Expense_Amount), 0.00), as ExpenseAmount, 
    Company_Information.Company_Name,
    Sales_Invoice.Invoice_No, Sales_Invoice.Invoice_Date, Sales_Invoice.Item_Name,
    New_Customer.Customer_Name, New_Customer.Customer_ID
from 
    Sales_invoice, Company_Information, New_Customer, Expense
where 
    Sales_Invoice.Customer_Id = New_Customer.Customer_ID 
    and Sales_Invoice.Invoice_No = Expense.Invoice_No
group by
    Company_Information.Company_Name,
    Sales_Invoice.Invoice_No, Sales_Invoice.Invoice_Date, Sales_Invoice.Customer_ID, 
    Sales_Invoice.Item_Name, New_Customer.Customer_Name, New_Customer.Customer_ID
```

The query is working well but if the `Expense` table has no values `Expense.Invoice_No` does not match with `Sales_Invoice.Invoice_No`, then the query above will return empty rows.

But what I wish to do is that, if `Expense.Invoice_No` does not exists then I still want to have my rows provided that expense amount return 0.00

Comment: For this question, I would change "the query above is working well" sentiment to be "it executes", or something in that matter; For, the query doesn't 'work well' if the joins aren't producing the results that you expect.  Also, the code snippet `, as ExpenseAmount` above seems wrong.

Comment: @Brett Caswell  the query above is working if I save somethings in expense tables but if I didn't save, I want it to return null

Comment: It's long past time you stopped using that ancient join syntax; it was superseded 27 years ago!

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins). Most likely if you switch to a proper `LEFT JOIN` you can achieve your goal

Comment: You're missing `Company_Information` in your implicit joins too; another reason to move to proper join syntax.

Comment: @larnu can u help me with the join syntax??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use standard joins! Then, you can easily handle "missing" relations with a `left join`.

Your question suggests:

```
select
    coalesce(sum(e.expense_amount), 0.00) as expenseamount, 
    ci.company_name,
    si.invoice_no, si.invoice_date, si.item_name,
    nc.customer_name, nc.customer_id
from new_customer nc
inner join company_information ci on ???
inner join sales_invoice si       on si.customer_id = nc.customer_id 
left join expense e               on e.invoice_no = si.invoice_no
group by
    ci.company_name,
    si.invoice_no, si.invoice_date, si.customer_id, 
    si.item_name, nc.customer_name, nc.customer_id
```

Note that you original code seems to me missing a join condition between the customers and companies. I represented it as `???` in the query.

You could also express the same logic with a correlated subquery, which would avoid outer aggregation:

```
select
    (
        select coalesce(sum(e.expense_amount), 0.00) 
        from expense e 
        where e.invoice_no = si.invoice_no
    ) as expenseamount, 
    ci.company_name,
    si.invoice_no, si.invoice_date, si.item_name,
    nc.customer_name, nc.customer_id
from new_customer nc
inner join company_information ci on ???
inner join sales_invoice si on si.customer_id = nc.customer_id
```

Comment: the company information does not have any ID reference, I just want to retrieve it with those tables

Comment: @Temitayo: so there is no relation at all between the companies and the other tables? That's a bit suprising, but in that case you would do: `from new_customer nc cross  join company_information ci inner join sales_invoices ...`. If there is more than one row in the companies table, this will multiply the rows though.

Comment: @Temitayo: without seeing your actual data, it is hard to suggest. Maybe you have customers without sales too (not only without expenses)? In that case, change the other inner join to a left join too.

Comment: I threw together this fiddle, but saw this answer before I finished.. feel free to check it out and play with it a bit. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c18a1/3